# if condition only searching for first row

Tags: php

I want to search in mysql table with specific column by using foreach with key value.

My code is:

```
$query= "select status from temp where id='1'";
$result=$oDbh->($query);
foreach($result AS $k => $v) {
   if($v['status']=='0' OR $v['status']=='1') {
      return true;
   }
   else {
      return false;
   }
}
```

In table temp status is `2,0,1,1,1,0`.

If condition is searching only for first row and its returning false still there is 0 or 1 in table.

I am new here if there is more info needed than comment, please.

Comment: why you search in foreach instead of adding params to SQL query?

Comment: Why not : `select status from temp where id='1' and status in (0,1)` ?

Comment: `where id='1'` means in _most_ tables, that you will get only 0 or 1 results back, since an id is normally a _unique_ identifier, and therefore only 1 of them exist and therefore maximal 1 row will be returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you expected it to do:

```
$query= "select status from temp where id='1'";
$result=$oDbh->($query);
foreach($result AS $k => $v) {
   if($v['status']=='0' OR $v['status']=='1') {
      return true;
   }
}
```

but based on your observation I would say you need to leverage the `continue` when they don't match. If you `return` then processing will stop -clearly. Unless I've grossly misunderstood your observation this will allow processing to continue until you either find a match or fall out of the loop completely.

Further, because you just didn't ask a clear enough question, it's just about impossible to determine what else is going on here, but I'm going to go out on a limb here and say that immediately after the loop (i.e. if you get there a match wasn't found), you're going to simply want to do this:

```
return false;
```

Comment: `continue` is useless here. You might as well omit the else clause altogether.

Comment: @Mischa, the only time you would be wrong in that assumption is if the OP didn't actually show **all** the code. Albeit that would be a mistake by the OP.

Comment: @BhagirathSingh, I'm glad I could be of assistance!